# Card declines with authorize.net when more than 1 numeric value in address field

Tags: commerce, entities, payment-gateways

I can't find any related issues reported in the commerce_authnet module, so I must be doing something wrong in the configuration of my site. At least once a week, sometimes a dozen times a week, a customer cannot complete their shopping cart order because Authorize.net declines their card for having an erroneous address.

After collecting months of data on this issue, it seems that when a second set of numerical values is entered into the address field, the information that is pushed to authorize.net is presented in the wrong format. For example, if you type in one of the following addresses, you would be declined:

21 8th Street

478 Commerce Way #4

6224 B Street Apt. 6

When the decline occurs, we receive the address information and enter it directly to the authorize.net portal, changing the "8th" to "Eighth" and moving the "Apt.6" to the second address line, and it works fine.

Can anyone help me understand how to adjust my configurations such that this is no longer a problem?

Or can you please give me an easy way to change the "Address 2" title to "Apt/Suite" in an attempt to circumvent the issues related to Apt/Suite?

Many, many thanks for any and all help!!

Edit: Drupal.org issue link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2545646

Comment: So is this confirmed as a weird quirk on Authorize.net's end? Or is it an issue with how the module is sending out data to Authorize.net? Co-maintainer of module here, if this is a bug in module highly recommend opening issue there (too)

Comment: Authorize.net, of course, claims it isn't them. We have no idea if that's true, but it is odd that others aren't complaining about the same thing in the module issues log. Therefore, I am thinking a work-around for relabeling "address 2" to "apt/suite" would at least take care of that problem. But if you think I should open an issue, then I will. We are getting desperate to fix this, since we have lost customers this way.

Comment: Are you using multiple languages or character sets on your site?

Comment: @ David Thomas Nope. Just English for now. I have adding multi-language to our site on my to-do list, but that's a low priority.